# Is it possible to use visibility guarantees instead of full-fledged locking for accessing shared state in a thread-safe way?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Java Concurrency in Practice states the following:

> When thread A executes a synchronized block, and subsequently thread B 
>   enters a synchronized block guarded by the same lock, the values of 
>   variables that were visible to A **prior to** releasing the lock are 
>   guaranteed to be visible to B upon acquiring the lock. In other words, 
>   everything A did **in** or **prior to** a synchronized block is visible to B when 
>   it executes a synchronized block guarded by the same lock.
>   Without synchronization, there is no such guarantee.

[image: Here's a diagram from the book]

The same logic applies to volatile variables:

> The visibility effects of volatile variables extend beyond the value
>   of the volatile variable itself. When thread A writes to a volatile
>   variable and subsequently thread B reads that same variable, the
>   values of all variables that were visible to A prior to writing to the
>   volatile variable become visible to B after reading the volatile
>   variable.

It's very clear from the description that you can use this visibility effect to actually replace (or limit the usage) of the traditional locks when you need to access some shared state. In the example from the diagram you can see that thread B can safely read the variable `y` even though it was changed in thread A outside the synchronized block.

So, is it safe to use this `visibility guarantee` when you change some shared state before taking the lock in on thread, then take the lock, do something (or nothing, I guess), release the lock and then in the other thread you acquire the same lock, release it and then safely read the latest values from shared variables that were updated in the first thread?

Comment: synchronization *ensures* that Thread A will finish that block before Thread B enters it. Whereas `volatile` will only take effect when Thread A and B do not read / write to a member at the same time. E.g. you have no guarantee which value will be written to and read from a member `m` when Thread A and B simultaniously write to it. What value Thread C receives is almost definetly non-deterministic (you simply can't surely know it)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what part of the question you're trying to answer. My question was primarily about the visibility guarantees that JVM provides when you releases the lock. In the example diagram that I mentioned you can see that the `y` variable is changed outside the synchronized block but still can be safely accessed from the thread B which accesses this variable after it releases the lock.

Comment: So you basically ask is it book lying to you or not? What reasob you have not to trust it and trust us instead?

Comment: I'm basically asking why should I use the synchronized block (or some lock object from java.util.concurrent.locks package) and put any code that deals with the shared state inside it, when I can use the technique that was described in the book and limit the usage of locks/synchronized block as much as possible (not including anything inside it, for example), because the `reader` thread will be able to get the recent changes anyway?

Comment: @J.Doe I answered exactly your last comment. You can't be sure that your `reader` thread encounters a valid value when you don't use `synchronization`, maybe it reads a value from a field at the exact same time when another thread is writing to it.

Comment: @Lino I didn't actually mean that. The thing that I'm trying to say is that it seems to me that you can do the following: 1 thread - change some shared state, acquire lock, release lock; 2 thread - acquire lock, release lock, access shared state. And it's guaranteed that your 2 thread will read the latest changes to shared state

Comment: *"So, is it safe to use this visibility guarantee"* - safe for which purpose? It's safe for some uses, not safe for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you get the `visibility guarantee` in the described way by using `volatile`, `synchronized` or either form of locking, but **nothing more**. Specifically you don't get mutual access and atomicity.

See also the sections in the JLS about the [memory model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) of the JVM and the [happens-before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) relation for much greater detail and depth.

Comment: Would it be safe to say that the following actions would guarantee the visibility of changes of some shared state between two threads, for example : 1 thread - change some shared state, acquire lock, release lock; 2 thread - acquire lock, release lock, access shared state?

Comment: From a pure visibility POV yes. However, you still have to ensure thread 1 acts on the lock before thread 2 by some other means.

Comment: But for the 2 thread it would be enough to just acquire/release the lock and then access the shared state that not necessarily had been changed by the 1 thread, correct?

Answer (score 2):

There is a key part in quoted sentence:

> The visibility effects of volatile variables extend beyond the value
>   of the volatile variable itself. **When thread A writes to a volatile
>   variable and subsequently thread B reads that same variable**, the
>   values of all variables that were visible to A prior to writing to the
>   volatile variable become visible to B after reading the volatile
>   variable.

While this is obviously true, you got here an condition about A writing prior B reading. **Order of read/write however cannot be guaranteed without locking** - and that is the whole point.

So you cannot replace every synchronization with volatiles as it will not yeld the same results.

Comment: I'm afraid you're missing this part of the sentence `all variables that were visible to A prior to writing to the volatile variable become visible to B after reading the volatile variable.`

Comment: What am i missing here? You just have no guarantees that write in A will be before B tries to read. So its not about "visibility" but about garantees of order of execution. I think that you misinterpret that sentence.

Comment: The part that says that you can basically change some shared state in one thread, and then write to a volatile variable. In the second thread you first read from that volatile variable and the access the shared state that was changed in the first thread. And it's guaranteed that you'll get the latest changes to this state.

Comment: But that only applies to that given order of exection - which is NOT GUARANTEED. Obviously READ after WRITE will yeld expected results, but first you must be sure that order of execution is sustained.

Comment: So what you saying is that read after write will give you "changes". What I am saying, is that you dont know it you will actually read after write.